# Let $G$ be a group. Prove that if $|G|=p^n$ with $p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $C(G) \neq {1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The only thing I could think was to use the Cauchy Theorem. So I know that exists a $h \in G$ such that $o(h) = p$. Also I can consider the subgroup $H = <h>$ that all the elements have the same property and $|H|=p$.

I think that $h \in C(G)$. But if I take $g \in G$, I'm not being able to prove that $g*h*g^{-1} = h$. To take an example I thought of $\mathbb{D}_4$, where $|\mathbb{D}_4|=8=2^3$ and I can see there that $r^2 \in \mathbb{D}_4$ has order 2 and $r^2 \in C(\mathbb{D}_4)$

Comment: Do you know about groups actions and the class formula?

Comment: I do know group actions. The class formula would be that a~b if exists g such that $gag^{-1}=b$?

Comment: @DaniSeidler: No, the class formula is a formula that expresses the cardinality of $G$ in terms of the size of its center and non-trivial conjugacy classes.

Comment: No, the class formula is what you get when you decompose the group into conjugacy classes using that and note that the fixed points together form the center. Then note that all other summands have orders divisible by $p$.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. Thanks. May I ask how you find it? I searched a while a couldn't. I suppoused that someone should've ask it before me.